# Просмотр назад с квантификатором

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, можно ли сделать просмотр назад с квантификатором?

Выражение: `(?<=[0-9]{1,})\s(?=[0-9]{1,})`

Ссылка на regex: https://regex101.com/r/8ukUh8/1

Comment: а что вы хотите в результате? например, так https://regex101.com/r/8ukUh8/2

Comment: Ничего не понял, но спасибо.

Comment: если не поняли, за что спасибо? :) вы хотите захватить пробел? Если вы по ссылке включите замены, то убедитесь, что пробел и заменяется - https://regex101.com/r/8ukUh8/3

Comment: Вам, скорее всего, не нужен ни просмотр назад, ни `\K`, просто нужно использовать захватывающую подмаску, `preg_replace('~(\d)\s(?=\d)~', '$1', $string)`. Да и `preg_replace('~(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)~', '', $string)` сойдёт.

Comment: @splash58 просто не понял как именно работает сочетание `?:` и `\K`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew благодарю. Сам пробел не проблема выделить, просто хотел понять можно ли использовать квантификатор при просмотре назад, чтобы, например, выделить букву `x` в строке `abc123x` примерно таким выражением `(?<=abc[0-9]{1,})x`

Comment: Можно, но не в регулярном выражении для PCRE.

Comment: Тут у вас проблема типа XY в вопросе. Не нужен вам "Просмотр назад с квантификатором". Просто не нужен именно в таком случае квантификатор.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew хорошо, спасибо.